# using input select to get value equals to all values

Tags: php, mysql, forms, input

I'm setting up a post form. The form itself is working, but I want to implement a "select all" input like

```
Select * FROM dbName WHERE something = '*'
```

I just dont know the function / setup to do this.

I got the input:

```
<select name ="Selector">
<option value="*">Text</option>
</select>
```

Also tried without any *

```
<select name ="Selector">
<option value="">Text</option>
</select>
```

The query is following:

```
$AllValues = $_POST['Selector'];
SELECT * FROM dbName WHERE columnName='$AllValues'
```

Comment: You may wish to re-asses how you are writing your access to the database as the method you are using opens a gaping security hole for SQL Injection attacks. Additionally, you are not assigning your SQL statement to a string, hence it would eval to an invalid line of php code.  In any case, you are probably looking for this command >> http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: The above code is not my working code on the site. its purely an example. But thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: i want to do a statement where i do like: SELECT * FROM db WHERE row = '(any value from the row)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

HTML:

```
  <select name ="Selector">
   <option value="">Text</option>
  </select>
```

PHP:

```
 $AllValues = $_POST['Selector'];

 $Where="";
 if($_POST['Selector']!=''){ // check condition for selector field, if it its value
      $Where = " WHERE columnName='$AllValues'";
 }
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbName  $Where ";
```

Comment: im gonna try this. ill be back

Comment: This worked out my issue. it was because of double AND in the query. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't work on Php. so i don't know whether we can do something like this but try this and let me know.

```
<select name ="Selector">
   <option value="1=1">Text</option>
</select>
```

Your query will be same

```
$AllValues = $_POST['Selector'];
SELECT * FROM dbName WHERE columnName='$AllValues'
```